# How to Resolve "ambiguous primary types or unused types" Error with _TypedDataEncoder.hash?

Tags: ethers.js, signature, hash, eip712

I am trying to compute the hash to be signed for EIP-712 typed data using the ethers.js(v5.7.2) library in TypeScript. I'm using `_TypedDataEncoder.hash()` to hash the typed data, but I am encountering the following error:

```
Error: ambiguous primary types or unused types: "PermitSingle", "EIP712Domain" (argument="types", value= {... }, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=hash/5.7.0)
```

Here is the TypeScript code I am using:

```typescript
import { arrayify, BytesLike, concat, hexlify } from '@ethersproject/bytes'
import { _TypedDataEncoder } from '@ethersproject/hash'
import { keccak256 } from '@ethersproject/keccak256'
import { TypedDataDomain, TypedDataField } from 'ethers'

function hashTypedDataV4(params: any) {
    // Destructure the params
    const [from, jsonData]: [string, string] = params;
    const { types, domain, primaryType, message } = JSON.parse(jsonData);

    // Hash the EIP-712 Domain
    const domainSeparator = _TypedDataEncoder.hashDomain(domain);

    // Hash the message (EIP-712 typed data)
    const messageHash = structHash(domain, types, message);

    // Compute the final hash to sign (according to EIP-712)
    const hashToSign = arrayify(keccak256(concat(['0x1901', domainSeparator, messageHash])));

    return hashToSign;
}

function structHash(domain: TypedDataDomain, types: Record<string, TypedDataField[]>, data: Record<string, any>) {
    return _TypedDataEncoder.hash(domain, types, data); // ERROR OCCURS HERE!
}
```

The error seems to occur on the return _TypedDataEncoder.hash(domain, types, data) line in the `structHash` method. From the error message, it seems like there is some ambiguity regarding the primary types, but I am not sure how to resolve it.

Below is an example of the params I am passing to hashTypedDataV4 (please note that the function expects the second element of params to be a JSON string, but I'm showing it as a JSON object for readability - you can use JSON.stringify() to convert it back to the expected format):

```json
[
  "0xfdb267dc5e340647aab9372fc5a8e406d4e71c8d",
  {
    "types": {
        "PermitSingle": [
            { "name": "details", "type": "PermitDetails" },
            { "name": "spender", "type": "address" },
            { "name": "sigDeadline", "type": "uint256" }
        ],
        "PermitDetails": [
            { "name": "token", "type": "address" },
            { "name": "amount", "type": "uint160" },
            { "name": "expiration", "type": "uint48" },
            { "name": "nonce", "type": "uint48" }
        ],
        "EIP712Domain": [
            { "name": "name", "type": "string" },
            { "name": "chainId", "type": "uint256"
            },
            { "name": "verifyingContract", "type": "address" }
        ]
    },
    "domain": { "name": "Permit2", "chainId": "1", "verifyingContract": "0x14a5698aeab8aa3f472c6d0a0061730f45467bd9"
    },
    "primaryType": "PermitSingle",
    "message": {
        "details": {
            "token": "0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2",
            "amount": "1461501637330902918203684832716283019655932542975",
            "expiration": "1690127209",
            "nonce": "0"
        },
        "spender": "0x49c4f688ade58ad80de1ddd932db3b804fef5cef",
        "sigDeadline": "1687537009"
    }
  }
]
```

Could anyone please help me understand what might be causing this error and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve the error, remove the `EIP712Domain` from `types` object (keep only `PermitSingle` and `PermitDetails` there). The domain type is inbuilt in the EIP712 standard and hence TypedDataEncoder so you do not need to specify it in the types. Hence the declared type `EIP712Domain` was unused and it was causing the error.

Here is a working piece of code:

```typescript
let result = _TypedDataEncoder.hash(
  {
    name: "Permit2",
    chainId: "1",
    verifyingContract: "0x14a5698aeab8aa3f472c6d0a0061730f45467bd9",
  },
  {
    PermitSingle: [
      { name: "details", type: "PermitDetails" },
      { name: "spender", type: "address" },
      { name: "sigDeadline", type: "uint256" },
    ],
    PermitDetails: [
      { name: "token", type: "address" },
      { name: "amount", type: "uint160" },
      { name: "expiration", type: "uint48" },
      { name: "nonce", type: "uint48" },
    ],
  },
  {
    details: {
      token: "0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2",
      amount: "1461501637330902918203684832716283019655932542975",
      expiration: "1690127209",
      nonce: "0",
    },
    spender: "0x49c4f688ade58ad80de1ddd932db3b804fef5cef",
    sigDeadline: "1687537009",
  }
);
console.log(result); 
// 0x3c636bc8d0efd7d4a25e31a001ea1a4743cd000a1148facaf1f60c4c5b327d40
```

Comment: Thanks, `delete types.EIP712Domain` works, I'll award the bounty closer to the end, in case there are other answers.